# Trouble in unistalling GRUB

Tags: grub2

I have a dual boot system in my laptop (windows 8 and ubuntu). I have decided to delete ubuntu and only use windows 8 in the system (I'm planning only to use ubuntu from usb boot). I tried to delete ubuntu partition from windows 8 and it wasn't ended up pretty good, I couldn't boot up to my windows 8 anymore. I've found that I need to uninstall GRUB first. I also found that I'll need a windows 8 recovery disk or bootable usb  to uninstalling GRUB but the problem is I can't boot up to my windows 8 bootable usb either (and I don't have any luck using recovery disk, mine is broken). How do I uninstalling GRUB then? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted your Ubuntu partition, you need to get to a windows 8 computer and create a recovery disk or usb. This is pretty simple, just type recovery in the search function.

When you boot from the recovery disk/drive, choose Command Prompt from the menu and type: `bootrec /fixmbr`

[How to create recovery drive in Windows 8](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/create-a-recovery-drive-in-windows-8/)